# Efficient file reading techniques in C#

Tags: c#-3.0

I am looking for the best way to read a CSV file line by line. I want to know what are the most efficient ways of doing the same. I am particulary concerned when the size of the file is big. Are the file reading utilities avilable in the .NET classes the most effient?

(PS: I have searched for the word 'Efficient' to know if someone has already posted similar question before posting this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this: [fast CSV Parser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx).

Here's the benchmark result:

> To give more down to earth numbers,
>   with a 45 MB CSV file containing 145
>   fields and 50,000 records, the reader
>   was processing about 30 MB/sec. So all
>   in all, it took 1.5 seconds! The
>   machine specs were P4 3.0 GHz, 1024
>   MB.

Answer (score 1):

The file handling in .NET is fine. If you want to read a line at a time in a comfortable way using `foreach`, I have a [simple `LineReader` class](http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=113) you might want to look at (with a more general purpose version in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil)).

With that you can use:

```
foreach (string line in new LineReader(file))
{
    // Do the conversion or whatever
}
```

It's also easily usable with LINQ. You may or may not find this helpful - if [the accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1769425/3834) works for you, that may be a better "off the shelf" solution.

Comment: Thanks Jon! I will surely have a look at it.